# How: getThresholdedImage with ruby-opencv

Tags: ruby, opencv

Can s.o help to translate this code to ruby-openvc?

**Original**
http://aishack.in/tutorials/tracking-colored-objects-in-opencv/

```
IplImage* GetThresholdedImage(IplImage* img)
{
  #Convert the image into an HSV image
  IplImage* imgHSV = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 8, 3);
  cvCvtColor(img, imgHSV, CV_BGR2HSV);

  #create a new image that will hold the threholded image (which will be returned).
  IplImage* imgThreshed = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 8, 1);

  #Now we do the actual thresholding:
  cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(20, 100, 100), cvScalar(30, 255, 255), imgThreshed)

  cvReleaseImage(&imgHSV);
  return imgThreshed;
}
```

**Translated**

```
    def getThresholdedImage2 (img)
  #blur the source image to reduce color noise
  img = img.smooth(CV_GAUSSIAN, 7, 7)

  #convert the image to hsv(Hue, Saturation, Value) so its
  #easier to determine the color to track(hue)  imgHSV = IplImage.new(img.width, img.height, 8, 3);
  imgHSV = img.BGR2HSV

  #create a new image that will hold the threholded image (which will be returned).
  imgThreshed = IplImage.new(img.width, img.height, 8, 1);

  #Now we do the actual thresholding:
  imgThreshed = imgHSV.in_range(CvScalar.new(20, 100, 100), CvScalar.new(30, 255, 255));


  return imgThreshed
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actally, I don't know ruby at all but it seems that I found solution to your problem. [Ruby-OpenCV](https://github.com/ruby-opencv/ruby-opencv) seems to be just a library-wrapper.

For example, if you want to find analogue of `cvInRangeS` function you should do the following.

By searching in source files I found [ext/opencv/cvmat.h](https://github.com/ruby-opencv/ruby-opencv/blob/master/ext/opencv/cvmat.h#L78) with this content:

```
VALUE rb_range(VALUE self, VALUE start, VALUE end);
VALUE rb_range_bang(VALUE self, VALUE start, VALUE end);
```

And in the [cpp](https://github.com/ruby-opencv/ruby-opencv/blob/master/ext/opencv/cvmat.cpp#L2324) file there's description:

```
/*
 * call-seq:
 *   in_range(<i>min, max</i>) -> cvmat
 *
 * Check that element lie between two object.
 * <i>min</i> and <i>max</i> should be CvMat that have same size and type, or CvScalar.
 * Return new matrix performed per-element,
 *  dst(I) = within the range ? 0xFF : 0
 */
```

So you should find all needed ruby functions by this way. Good luck!

Comment: thanks. But i can't find the right translation for 'cvScalar(20, 100, 100)'  // Code updadet in original post

Comment: There are still some methods i can't find. E.g. // cvCreateStructuringElementEx(11, 11, 5,  5,  CV_SHAPE_RECT, NULL);

Comment: @fabian why should I search it for you? It's `rb_cvCreateStructuringElementEx`. Use file search in your file manager.

Comment: I already tried that method 'undefined method `rb_cvCreateStructuringElementEx' for main:Object (NoMethodError)' for   test = rb_cvCreateStructuringElementEx(21, 21, 10, 10, CV_SHAPE_RECT, nil);

Comment: Sorry, I don't know ruby - you should experiment with it by yourself.

Comment: Thank you. Which language do you use/recommend for simple opencv projects? I just want to detect tennis balls in a picture and upload the results to a webserver.

Comment: @fabian OpenCV is originally written on c++. But there's a good java wrapper. You can try it.